# How to add a user to a group in FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, users

How can I add an existing user to a group in FreeBSD?  The command `usermod` does not work.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`pw` is the command you are looking for. To add user `klaatu` to the group `foo`, do:

```
pw groupmod foo -m klaatu
```

Here is the FreeBSD handbook page on the subject. It's an easy and informative read:
[Users and Basic Account Management](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/users-synopsis.html)

Answer (score 2):

Wheel is famous for FreeBSD, if you want to need to use su command, you need to be member of wheel group, So pw groupadd get a groupName and -m get members of your group.Old style of the following command you needed to extra command.

```
pw groupadd wheel -m mohsen,ali,john,Hilary,Kate
```

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are all good.  This also works:

```
pw usermod john -G mygroup
```

Comment: But it will erase john from all other groups that he was previously in...

Answer (score 1):

**Task: Add existing user to group**

You would like to add existing user tom to secondary group called ftpusers. Type the command as follows:

```
# pw usermod tom -G ftpusers
```

You can add tom to secondary group ftpuser and wwwusers:

```
pw usermod tom -G ftpusers,wwwusers
```

`-G` option Set the default groups in which new users are granted membership. This is a separate set of groups from the primary group, and you should avoid nominating the same group as both primary and extra groups.

**Task: Add a new user to group**

Add new user jerry to system and to secondary group sales:

```
# pw useradd jerry -G sales
# passwd jerry
```

First command adds user jerry to secondary group called sales. Second commands set a password for jerry.